# how to link to plantuml diagram in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to add some UML diagrams to my *.dox document, with these requirements:

- I'd like to include plain PlantUML document, without doxygen tags in it.
- I want it as link to image in my final document, instead of having it on the main page directly.

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is currently not possible, there is no command similar to `@dotfile`, `@mscfile` or `@diafile` which does this for dot, msc or dia source files. But if you want to reuse the same diagram in different pages of the documentation you can let doxygen generate a png file from the code and just include the png file:

```
\startuml [{file}] ["caption"] [<sizeindication>=<size>]

e.g.:
@startuml{myimage.png} "Image Caption" width=5cm
```

I did not try this, but this way you might workaround this, you could create an extra page in a .h, .dox or .txt file containing a doxygen comment, where you put all your diagrams in. From this file doxygen generates the png files. Those png files you might embed using the `@image` command.

Comment: It is possible with preprocessing as mentioned by [Denis_Sergee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8859632/denis-sergeev)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve first requirement try using [Plantuml preprocessing](http://plantuml.com/preprocessing). Like this:

```
  /**
   * @startuml
   * !include my_diagram.txt!0
   * @enduml
   */
```

Second requirement, as I know, is not supported by Doxygen so far.

Comment: Maybe worth an enhancement request at doxygen: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: It works if plantuml.jar path is properly configured. Why is the `!0` needed at the end?

Comment: I tried using the suggested solution. Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work, as I was not able to figure out in which folder the plantuml textfile needs to be added.

Comment: @sensslen

> I was not able to figure out in which folder the plantuml textfile needs to be added

Apparently it has to be in the same directory where documentation is being generated, which seems not a very useful default. It looks like first doxygen splits out the inline part between startuml/enduml into a separate file called inline_umlgraph_svghtml.pu in the output directory, then runs plantuml there.

Comment: You can set PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH though: that works for me.  https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_plantuml_include_path